# modx вывод последних тем с форума ipb

Tags: modx, ipb

Есть сайт на modx (MODX 3.0.1) и есть форум ipb (Invision Community v4.7.1), php 8.1.
Хочу вывести последние темы с форума ipb на сайт modx.
На просторах интернета нашел статьи по интеграции modx и vbulletin (
https://habr.com/ru/post/93572/ ), а также вывод тем с форума vbulletin на сайт modx ( https://habr.com/ru/post/93943/ ).
Пытался делать по аналогии с этими статьями..
Из первой статьи не понял от куда появился global $vbulletin;
Возможно я не понял какой файл из ipb нужно было скопировать в global_modx.php, поэтому решил пропустить..

```
Для начала нам необходимо подготовиться, и первым будет файл global.php форума.
Я сделал так: скопировал его в global_modx.php (.../forum/global_modx.php), открыл для редактирования и удалил все после 891 строки (напоминаю, версия форума 3.8.1) — подключение стилей и т.д., т.е. последней строчкой в файле у меня вызов функции verify_ip_ban();
```

Из статьи про вывод тем с форума вроде все понятно. Заменяю названия таблиц и столбиков на ipbшные, добавляю подключение к внешней БД форума и получается вот такое:

```
<?php
define('MODX_CORE_PATH', '/path/to/revo/core/');
define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY','config');
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'model/modx/modx.class.php';
 
// Задаем подключения к сторонней базе данных:
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '123456';
$dbname = 'forum';
$port = 3306;
$charset = 'utf8';
 
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$xpdo = new xPDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$count = 10;
$forumlink = 'https://forum.mysite.ru/';
$sql = 'SELECT title as topic,tid,last_post,last_poster_id,last_poster_name,title_seo
FROM `forums_topics`
WHERE forum_id NOT IN ()
ORDER BY `last_post` DESC
LIMIT '.$count.';';
        
$res = $xpdo->query($sql); 
$txt = '';

while ($f_res = $modx->db->getRow($res, 'assoc')) {
//элементы массива названы вполне себе понятно
$txt .= $modx->parseChunk('forum_last_messages', 
    array(
        'forumlink' => $forumlink,
        'postid' => $f_res['last_poster_id'],                  
        'threadtitle' => $f_res['topic'],
        'title_seo' => $f_res['title_seo'],
        'lastposter' => $f_res['last_poster_name'],
        'forum' => $f_res['forum'],
        'postdate' => date("H:i", $f_res['last_post'])   //формат даты
        ),
    '[+',
    '+]'
    );
}
return $txt;
```

По итогу на сайте ошибка

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `last_post` DESC LIMIT 10' at line 3 in /public_html/core/vendor/xpdo/xpdo/src/xPDO/xPDO.php:2549 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/core/vendor/xpdo/xpdo/src/xPDO/xPDO.php(2549): PDO->query('SELECT title as...') #1 /public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modx/revolution/modsnippet/17.include.cache.php(25): xPDO\xPDO->query('SELECT title as...') #2 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modScript.php(88): include('/home/zamorinpa...') #3 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modParser.php(505): MODX\Revolution\modScript->process(NULL) #4 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modParser.php(218): MODX\Revolution\modParser->processTag(Array, true) #5 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResource.php(521): MODX\Revolution\modParser->processElementTags('', '...', true, false, '[[', ']]', Array, 9) #6 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResource.php(469): MODX\Revolution\modResource->parseContent() #7 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResponse.php(72): MODX\Revolution\modResource->prepare() #8 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modRequest.php(154): MODX\Revolution\modResponse->outputContent(Array) #9 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modRequest.php(138): MODX\Revolution\modRequest->prepareResponse() #10 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modX.php(1495): MODX\Revolution\modRequest->handleRequest() #11 /public_html/index.php(63): MODX\Revolution\modX->handleRequest() #12 {main} thrown in /public_html/core/vendor/xpdo/xpdo/src/xPDO/xPDO.php on line 2549

В строке WHERE forum_id NOT IN () исправил WHERE forum_id NOT IN (0), забыл 0.
Теперь ошибка вот такая

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRow() on null in /public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modx/revolution/modsnippet/17.include.cache.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modScript.php(88): include() #1 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modParser.php(505): MODX\Revolution\modScript->process(NULL) #2 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modParser.php(218): MODX\Revolution\modParser->processTag(Array, true) #3 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResource.php(521): MODX\Revolution\modParser->processElementTags('', '...', true, false, '[[', ']]', Array, 9) #4 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResource.php(469): MODX\Revolution\modResource->parseContent() #5 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modResponse.php(72): MODX\Revolution\modResource->prepare() #6 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modRequest.php(154): MODX\Revolution\modResponse->outputContent(Array) #7 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modRequest.php(138): MODX\Revolution\modRequest->prepareResponse() #8 /public_html/core/src/Revolution/modX.php(1495): MODX\Revolution\modRequest->handleRequest() #9 /public_html/index.php(63): MODX\Revolution\modX->handleRequest() #10 {main} thrown in /public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modx/revolution/modsnippet/17.include.cache.php on line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Само подключение к базе удалось? Проверить можно так:

```
echo $o = ($xpdo->connect()) ? 'Подключено' : 'Ошибка подключения';
```

И далее

```
 if ($res) {
        $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $res->closeCursor();
        print_r($row);
 }else{
        print_r($res->errorInfo());
 }
```

Comment: Вот такое выводит:   ПодключеноArray ( [topic] => ���� 2 ������� [tid] => 3 [last_post] => 1662525600 [last_poster_id] => 1 [last_poster_name] => Mark_Dev )

Comment: Примерно понял в какую сторону нужно копать, заработало вот с таким кодом   
    while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
//элементы массива названы вполне себе понятно
$txt .= $modx->parseChunk('forum_last_messages',
    array(
 'threadtitle' => $row['topic'],
 'postid' => $row['tid'],
 'forumlink' => $forumlink,
 'postdate' => date("H:i", $row['last_post']),
 'lastposterid' => $row['last_poster_id'],
 'lastposter' => $row['last_poster_name'],
 'title_seo' => $row['title_seo'] 
 ),
    '[+',
    '+]'
    );
}

$res->closeCursor();

return $txt;

Comment: Данные в чанк передаются, но иероглифы остаются...  ���� 2 �������. Пока не понял как их заставить отображаться русскими буквами(

Comment: У вас в подключении utf8, а что за кодировка у базы/таблиц, из которых запрашиваете? Вероятно "ромбики" из-за несовпадения кодировок

Comment: В файле conf_global.php 'sql_utf8mb4' => true. В БД Сравнение - utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Ниже есть еще cp1251_general_ci. Я пробовал выставить в $charset = 'utf8'; $charset = 'utf8mb4'; $charset = 'cp1251'; Ничего не меняется.

Comment: Добавил $res = $xpdo->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");  Перед выполнением запроса $res = $xpdo->query($sql); И отобразились букавки. Тогда не понятно для чего тут указывать кодировку $charset = 'utf8';